File upload via robot framework
In our application , we have "import" button with this [id="content-import-action"] , once we clicks on the button filebrowser will open where user can select the file and import.
Below steps i tried via robot fraework
1: Choose File  [id="content-import-action"]  , but this steps didnt worked out.
2: Then i realised , once we click on abve element , there is one additional element is showing in DOM
<input type="file" hidden="true" accept=".json" data-testid="content-import-action" data-insights="content-import-action" aria-labelledby="content-import-action"> 
Click Element  [id="content-import-action"]
Choose File   [data-testid="content-import-action"] ${file_path}
The above 2 steps actually solved the file upload , but unfortunately file browser is still showing up in UI even after file upload.
Any suggestions to solve this issue..?
Tried steps mentioned in description

I would try to use Choose File directly on the hidden input element. Don't activate the operating system file chooser.
Alternatively, just proceed with the test case, by ignoring the opened file chooser window (if it is not modal).

If i use only the Choose File , framework not able to find the element and exiting with exception.

@Hello : may be I can try to ignore and continue the operation. But to be honest, it doesn't look good and doesn't satisfy me.
can we try to close the window model via pywin auto or sikuli ..?

Is there any way , i can close the file browser via "ESC" button. manually if we do it is closing.
I tried below option , and it is not closing
Press Keys    None   ESC

@soumya You should try to avoid having the file browser dialog opened, do not click the element.

With out clicking on the element , I am not able to do the "Choose File" operation as the second element coming up in DOM only after clicking the first element
@Helio
